# JText::_ not working

Tags: joomla, components, joomla1.5

There's the thing:
I have created complete Joomla1.5 component, added language ini file for JText::_ translation, it gets loaded during installation, but translation doesn't work.

Here's the language part of xml manifest file (it is supposed to work only in the admin):

```
<administration>
  (...)     
  <languages folder="admin/language">
    <language tag="pl-PL">pl-PL.com_COMPONENTNAME.ini</language>
  </languages>

</administration>
```

file pl-PL.com_COMPONENTNAME.ini resides in admin/language/ in the installation pack, after installation it's loaded to the administrator/language/ folder, but JText::_() method doesn't seem to read it.

I tried JFactory::getLanguage()->load('com_COMPONENTNAME'), no effect tho.

Here's part of the ini file (I tried both with and without double quotes):

```
# $Id: pl-PL.com_COMPONENTNAME.ini
# author

AGENTS="Agenci"
AGENT="Agent"
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I'm stumped on this problem as well.

Answer (score 3):

I know, 5 years too late... but finally an answer. ;)

You are missing the lang subfolder. Correct would be:

```
 <languages folder="administrator/language">
    <language tag="pl-PL">pl-PL/pl-PL.com_yourcomponentname.ini</language>
  </languages>
```

[Joomla Language Management](https://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Adding_language_management)

You can also use local language files without adding them to the manifest:
https://docs.joomla.org/Specification_of_language_files

Comment: No idea whether this one works or not, since I'm too far from Joomla for.. a few years now ;) Up for the effort, and will accept as soon as someone confirms it to be right.

Comment: Thanks for that, @dennis-heiden.  It just so happens, I got saddled with a Joomla1.5 and I've been spending the last few days beating my head against this.